# Use Maven Timestamp in Footer for Copyright

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I want to Use the Maven Timestamp in the Footer of a Webpage as Copyright Date. How can i do this? I am new To maven and have no idear how to do.

Comment: How is your web page implemented? Did you try out maven plugins that can replace text in files? Do you mean the build timestamp with "Maven Timestamp"?

Answer (score 1):

I try to give the file to maven with

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/templates</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>footer.html</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

With the properties

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a properties section to you pom file

```
<properties>
   <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

Then add a build.properties to your src/main/resouces

```
version=${project.version}
timestamp=${timestamp}
```

Then you need to filter the properties so in the build section of your pom :

```
<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
   </resources>
```

Then your properties file in the target/classes directory will be like :

```
version=2.0.4
timestamp=2016-07-22 09:45
```

And available on the app's class path.

Comment: can i use the variable directly in the html? 'Like © ${maven.build.timestamp}'

Comment: no, you'll need to look at JSPs for that, I've only answered the maven bit.

Comment: Add ${timestamp} in your html file, then use the answer by Marcel Wolf, above.  I assumed you might want the timestamp available in Java code, but I don't think you do.

Comment: well, it doesn't.   I search for an solution of this

Comment: Works fine, I just tested it.

Comment: just one thing, mabe a bit offtopic to this. the rendered file is not included in the rest of the build. how can i paste it back?

Comment: You don't need or want to change the original, the runtime in the target is rendered at build time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118917/discussion-between-marcel-wolf-and-essex-boy).